# PHP Page Count On Refresh

Tags: php

What is the best way to count each page in the code below when the page is refreshed.  I do not know how many pages there will be but I do need to implement a page system as the api only allows 100 records at a time

**Code:**

```
$o = new Hotels_CloudBeds($credentials);

$propertyID = 29    
$pageSize = 100; //max == 100
$pageNumber = 1;
$total = 100;
$count = 0;

$guests = array();
$emails = array();


$url = 'https://hotels.cloudbeds.com/api/v1.1/getGuestsModified?propertyID=%s&pageSize=%s&pageNumber=%s';
$response = $o->curl(sprintf($url, $propertyID, $pageSize, $pageNumber));
$json = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: sessions may be helpful.

Comment: So are you trying to paginate your api response?

Comment: @AdamForbis Yes I am

Comment: And you just need to know how to count how many items are returned for a page?

Comment: Not as such,  I know that it allows a return of 100 per page so I need to somehow cycle through all the pages fetch the data and when it gets to a end point start at 1 again

Comment: So you dont want to use  JS localstorage . then a session  value counter should work

Comment: So are you wanting to a looped pagination and reset your page number when it starts over again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continual counter regardless of page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572762/continual-counter-regardless-of-page-refresh)

Comment: @AdamForbis Yes :)

Comment: @zod Can I have an example plz

Comment: @AdamForbis Could I please have an example :)

Comment: @JessMcKenzie I'm trying to work out an answer that will describe what I'm thinking. You may need to provide some feedback on it though.(Especially since I don't know what html your working with)

Comment: @AdamForbis Thanks means alot,  I am working with no html its straight data from an array from there its going to be inserted so there is no visual aspect

Comment: @JessMcKenzie I'm not sure if we are thinking of the same kind of problem but I'll go ahead and post my thoughts as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question broken down into smaller parts:

1. Keep the page state(page count, page size, etc...)

This part is easy enough. You can use GET, POST, or SESSION variables to hold the current state of the page. I would personally use GET to allow for easy linking of the page.

2. When is the end of the results?

This is the harder part of the question. When the total count of the items are not provided you essentially have to tell if it is the end by the result of your request.

So if there are less beds returned from the api than the page size it should mean that is the last page.

If no results are returned we have gone of the end of the results and we should just redirect to the first page.(this will happen if the beds are evenly divisible by the page size)

That should be enough for basic looped pagination.