# Continuously working counter Laravel - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel, counter

I'm trying to use a counter that never stops, even when the user leaves the page. I want it works continuously, but I don't know the way to do that. At this moment, I have a counter which keeps counting while the user is on the page even if the user updates it, but it's never going to keep counting when the user leaves.

How can I do that or what tutorial can you recommend me?

**I have this code that I got here:** [Continual counter regardless of page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572762/continual-counter-regardless-of-page-refresh)

```
var counter=22000000000;
if(typeof(localStorage.getItem('counts'))!='object')
{
   counter=parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counts'));
}
setInterval(function () {
    $(".count").html(counter);
    ++counter;
    localStorage.setItem('counts',counter);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're incrementing the counter every second, why not just store the timestamp at which the user first visited the site and deduct it from the current timestamp.

Note that using `localStorage()` does not work on StackOverflow snippets or JS fiddle, but you can see it here: https://js.do/code/271017

```js
if(localStorage.getItem('start')===null)
{
   localStorage.setItem('start',new Date().getTime());
}
setInterval(function () {
 var t = new Date().getTime();
    var s = localStorage.getItem('start');
    $(".count").html(Math.round((t-s)/1000));
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p class="count"></p>
```

This does not use Laravel in any way. If the user is logged in to your site with Laravel you could store the start time in your database to avoid the user being able to reset the counter by clearing their cookies.

Comment: Great idea, so you're saying that I can save in my database the start time of the user and then get it?

Comment: Another question, how can I sum the counter? What if I want to sum 32 per second? It's just that I'm new for this.

Comment: The `Math.round((t-s)/1000)` bit takes the number of milliseconds between now and the time the user first visited the page and divides it by 1000 to get seconds. If you wanted 32 "units" per second, you would just multiply this number by 32: `Math.round((t-s)/1000)*32`

Comment: If the user is logged in, you could add a column to your `users` table called `start_time`, and when they first visit/register set `$user->start_time = time(); $user->save();` and then in your blade template replace `localStorage.getItem('start');` with  `{{ $user->start_time }}`.

Comment: In this case, I just created a counter for a post, so I think that I could replace it for the “created_at” date of the post. Is that right?

Comment: `$post->created_at->getTimestamp()*1000` (remember js `.getTime()` returns milliseconds whereas php `getTimestamp()` returns seconds, so you'll need to multiply the PHP one by 1000 as shown here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185560/discussion-between-danhergir-and-lufc).